# Generate all distinct partitions of `n` balls into bins

Tags: python, algorithm, partitioning

Given 3 balls, there are 3 ways to partition them into bins:

```
(3)
(2,1)
(1,1,1)
```

Note that `(1,2)` is already covered in `(2,1)`, since we don't care about the order of the bins.

I'd like to write a function that gets the number of balls `n` and outputs all  possible partitions, in an efficient way.

This is what I came up with:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce
def all_partitions(n):
    n_bits_on=set([tuple(reduce(lambda x,y:x[:y]+[1]+x[y+1:],c,[0]*(2*n-1))) for c in combinations(range(2*n-1),n)])
    return set([tuple(sorted(filter(lambda i:i>0,reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y] if y==0 else x[:-1]+[x[-1]+1,],p,[0])))) for p in n_bits_on])
```

What the code does is:

1. Generate all bit-arrays of size `2n-1` and `n` bits on (using `itertools.combinations`)
2. Regard zeros as partitions and ones as balls - sum the number of ones between two zeros (with `reduce`)
3. Sorting all options, and removing duplicates with `set()`

*The code works*, but it is very slow.

Any ideas how can it be improved ?